# iOS / Titanium: Clear Button cannot be seen on a TextField with a black background

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I want to add the clear button on the `TextField` like so:

```
<TextField clearButtonMode-"Titanium.UI.INPUT_BUTTONMODE_ALWAYS" backgroundColor="black"/>
```

The clear button usually looks like this:

[image: Clear Button Example]

However the issue is that the background of the TextInput is black. This means the clear button cannot be seen.

How can I change the appearance or colour of the clear button so this is not an issue?

Comment: First thing I would like to ask is that TextField does really exist?
You should use TextFiled instead

Comment: @Mitul Bhalia sorry just a typo. Edited

Answer (score 1):

I know that it should work but if its an ti sdk issue then you should try to test it with other ti sdks.

If you find same issue then you can file a JIRA issue with test app and then you can use rightButton property to achieve what you want.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-rightButton

Comment: You know what should work? Whats your solution exactly?

Comment: i meant that the clearButtonMode with backgroundColor should work but it does not then you can try above solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

To be completely honest man. you could just add a view inside the textField.  I think its bit more efficient anyways and if you code by percentages as long as your border radius is more then half the height it will be circle.